# Why I have been accessing the docker daemon on another machine and it always fails

Tags: docker

I want to access the docker daemon on another machine,but it always fails.

Both machines are virtual machines.

**systemctl status docker service**

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-04-16 07:38:52 EDT; 3s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 5191 (dockerd)
   Memory: 128.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─5191 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

**ps -ef | grep docker**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef | grep docker
root       5191      1  1 07:38 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
root       5800   5161  0 07:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

**netstat -tulp**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4373/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4134/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN      4373/master         
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2375               [::]:*                  LISTEN      5191/dockerd        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2377               [::]:*                  LISTEN      5191/dockerd        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7946               [::]:*                  LISTEN      5191/dockerd        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      4134/sshd
```

Result of access on another machine

```
[root@localhost dack]# docker -H tcp://192.168.233.150:2375 images
error during connect: Get http://192.168.233.150:2375/v1.39/images/json: dial tcp 192.168.233.150:2375: connect: no route to host
[root@localhost dack]# docker -H tcp://192.168.233.150:2375 info
error during connect: Get http://192.168.233.150:2375/v1.39/info: dial tcp 192.168.233.150:2375: connect: no route to host
```

Comment: Is the remote system compromised?  If it's a VM I'd delete it and start over.  Opening access to the Docker socket like this opens up network-visible unencrypted unauthenticated root access to the system; Google "Docker cryptojacking", and do _not_ set the relevant Docker daemon option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for firewall, if 2375 port is allowed to connect from other servers.